# InAppBrowser issue on phonegap 2.7.0

Tags: cordova, xcode4.5, phonegap-build, inappbrowser

Iam working with a phonegap app, i have used **InAppBrowser** in my project but when i clicked the link, xcode console shows the below error:

> "Failed to load webpage with error: The requested URL was not found on
>   this server."

and my code will look like:

```
<a href=”#” onclick='window.open(‘www.google.com',’_blank‘,’location=yes‘,’closebuttoncaption=Return‘);'>Click Here</a>
```

iam using xcode 4.5 and phonegap 2.7.0. I really got stuck, please help.

Comment: Are you mixing the usage of quotes?  If I read your code correctly, you are either closing the quote for `onclick` at the beginning of `url` or you are sending in the literal string of `url,`. Please verify. I would advice you to use `onclick="..."` and then you can use single quotes within it `''` to reduce confusion and necessity of escaping.

Comment: thanks!! now it works, it has problem on quotes which is copied from browser along the code..

Comment: Did you change your question code to the correct working code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the correct form of this should be

```
<a href=”#” onclick="window.open('http://www.google.com', '_blank', 'location=yes');">Click Here</a>
```

This is based on the documented version from the [PhoneGap 2.7.0 Documentation](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.7.0/cordova_inappbrowser_inappbrowser.md.html#close).

It appears that the `closebuttoncaption=Return` parameter you have added is not actually in the specification.

Answer (score 0):

```
var myURL = encodeURI('http://www.google.com');
window.open(myURL, '_blank', 'location=yes');
```

You can refer below link :-

[Phonegap App : External URL don't open in InApp Browser of IOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17569787/phonegap-app-external-url-dont-open-in-inapp-browser-of-ios/17587374#17587374)