# Phonegap App : External URL don't open in InApp Browser of IOS

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cordova, inappbrowser

External URLs don't open in the system's browser in my PhoneGap IOS application. I'm using PhoneGap Build 2.7.0.

**Javascript:**

`window.open(myURL, '_blank', 'location=yes');`

**Config.xml**

```
<plugins>
    <plugin name="InAppBrowser" value="CDVInAppBrowser" />
</plugins>

<access origin="*" />
```

How to solve this? when i using the url "www.google.com" it works fine but when i used required url for my app it did not worked even that url works fine in browser.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Javascript:`

```
myURL = encodeURI(myURL);
window.open(myURL, '_blank', 'location=yes');
```

> **Using of encodeURI method fix the above issue**

Answer (score 1):

Take reference from [this](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iOS/ChildBrowser) link. 
I have used this plugin for my IOS application development way back. It works like a charm.
Also, it is easy to integrate.

Hope it helps !

Comment: The link you'd used is dead.